# AppDelegate から ViewController へ UINavigationController を使って遷移したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

現在、プッシュ通知で投げたURLを、AppDelegateで受け取って、WebViewで表示しようとしています。

なお、そのWebViewは、そのためだけに使うものではなく、別の場面でも使っているViewです。

具体的には、ニュースアプリのような感じで、まずタブがあり、それぞれのタブには記事のリストがあり、タップすると「DetailViewController」へ遷移します。このDetailViewControllerをそのまま利用したいと考えています。

別の書き方をすると、UITabBarControllerに、UINavigationControllerが乗っていて、そこへFirstViewController（記事リストページ）-> DetailViewController（記事閲覧ページ）へ遷移するという感じです。伝わりますでしょうか…。

ここから、本題になります。
プッシュ通知で受け取ったURL（こちらは取得確認済み）を、AppDelegateからDetailViewControllerへ直接飛ばそうとしています。

コードは、AppDelegate.m内の「※追記3 <del>willFinishLaunchingWithOptions</del>」に、下記のような形で遷移を試みていますが、思ったように動作しておりません。

どなたか動くコードに心当たりのある方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
AppDelegate.m

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
FirstViewController *firstView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];
DetailViewController* detailView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];
detailView.URL = URL;
[navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
```

**追記2**
プッシュ通知に、Growth Pushというサービスを利用しています。
プッシュ通知自体の実装は下記ページを参照しております。
http://growthhack.sirok.co.jp/growthpush/4371/

**追記3**
willFinishLaunchingWithOptionsに直接コードを書いた場合、実行されないとのことで、記述場所を変更いたしました。ですので、一旦アラートビューを出し「はい」を選択した場合に、DetailViewControllerに飛ぶように試みています。

Comment: その提示コードは、どこに書いてあるのですか？そこを明記するよう、質問文を編集していただけたらと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記いたしました。

Comment: いや、だからAppDelegateクラスの、どのメソッド（例：
 `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ）に書いてあるのか？ということをおたずねしたのですが……

Comment: お手数お掛けして申し訳ございません。追記いたしました。

Comment: 「willFinishLaunchingWithOptions」メソッドは、アプリ起動時に1度だけ呼ばれるDelegateメソッドなので、プッシュ通知を受け取ったあとには、実行されません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。てっきりその一回で呼び出されているかと思っておりました。お恥ずかしい。

今度は、UIAlertViewを使って、「はい」を押した場合に、DetailViewControllerを呼び出してみました。

その結果、モーダルビューだと、表示されたのですが、最初の質問で記述したUINavigationControllerを使ったコードだと表示されずでした。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしました。
AppDelegateで受け取ったURLを、そのままFirstViewControllerに渡して、そこを起点に遷移するだけでした。

それと、モーダルビューで表示されたのは、勘違いでした。UINavigationControllerに、self.window.rootViewControllerを入れていました。消すとモーダルビューも動きませんでした。